# Listing names with if elseif else

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to list names except for id 36.  This is what I have but it's not working.  Can some one help?

```
$sql = "SELECT `ls_names`.`id` , `ls_names`.`name` FROM `thedb`.`ls_names` ";  
$names = mysql_query($sql);
if(count($names) > 0)
    $row_count = count($names);
elseif ($names . $id = 36)
    echo '';
else
    $row_count = 1;
```

Comment: You should use `mysqli_*` statements.

Comment: ..or PDO and (either way) prepared statements (though not especially relevant here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this bit:  `elseif ($names . $id = 36)`

You are not doing a comparison on this line, you are doing an assignment.  Change it to:

```
elseif ($names . $id == 36)
```

Furthermore, the `$names` variable is only the result from the query, so as it is a resource concatenating `$id` isn't doing what you are expecting.

Comment: look at the OPs code again. `$names` is the query, not the fetched result, so `$names . $id` is not what the OP thinks it is.

Comment: @Sean Good call, I overlooked that.  I'll edit now.

Answer (score 0):

Get only data except id 36, then use Where Clause in sql query, then display

```
$sql = "SELECT `ls_names`.`id` , `ls_names`.`name` FROM `thedb`.`ls_names` Where `ls_names`.`id` NOT IN (36)";
```

Answer (score 0):

`$names` is set to the result of `mysql_query`.  From http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php:

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.

`count()` on the other hand takes a `Countable` - is a mysql resource a Countable?  Shouldn't you be using `mysql_num_rows` to count the number of rows in the response?

In what way would concatenating `$names` to `$id` (the definition of which you don't show ) be a valid string?

I think if you walk through your `if` statement you'll realize it's pathological.  Think about it:

```
if( number_of_rows > 0 )
  $row_count = number_of_rows
elsif result_set . $id == 36 
  echo '' 
else
  row_count = 1
```

That doesn't achieve anything obvious as far as I can tell.

Finally, as another answer suggests, if you want filter results from a database, have the *database* filter the results, don't do it in PHP.  The database is very good at this kind of thing.  Moving this code into PHP is a common antipattern.

Comment: my guess is that the OP thinks that `$names . $id` is the same as `$row['id']` (where `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($names)`)

Answer (score 0):

Executing the query and retrieving the results are done in 2 seperate steps. And the code you've shown us does not match the problem you describe:

"I'm trying to list names except for id 36"

Then try:

```
$sql = "SELECT `ls_names`.`id` , `ls_names`.`name`"
     ." FROM `thedb`.`ls_names` ";  
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   if (36!=$row['id']) {
      echo $row['name'] . ",";
   }
}
```

But filtering the data after retrieving it from the database is bad practice. If you don't need the data, dont' fetch it:

```
 SELECT id, name FROM thedb.ls_names WHERE id <> 36
```